# Cargo test pass on local machine but fails on github actions

Tags: rust, github-actions, rust-cargo, serde, actix-web

I wrote a test to verify the POST was parsed correctly. Here is the endpoint:

```
#[post("/test_weather_data")]
pub(crate) async fn test_weather_data_post(weather_data: String) -> Result<String> {
    let wd: Vec<Reading> = serde_json::from_str(&*weather_data).unwrap();

    Ok(format!("id: {}, index: {}", &wd[0].id, &wd[0].index))
}
```

And the test:

```
#[actix_rt::test]
async fn test_weather_data_ok() {
    let mut app = test::init_service(App::new().service(controller::test_weather_data_post)).await;

    let payload = r#"[{"measurement_time_default":"2021-03-24T20:50:00+01:00","id":228,"index":201,"field_description":"relative_humidity","measurement":77.5}]"#;

    let resp = test::TestRequest::post()
        .uri("/test_weather_data")
        .header(header::CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .set_payload(payload)
        .send_request(&mut app)
        .await;

    let result = test::read_body(resp).await;

    assert_eq!(result, "id: 228, index: 201".as_bytes());
}
```

The struct:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Insertable)]
pub struct Reading {
    #[serde(with = "my_date_format")]
    pub measurement_time_default: DateTime<Local>,
    pub id: i32,
    pub index: i32,
    pub field_description: String,
    pub measurement: f32,
}
```

Module my_date_format:

```
mod my_date_format {
    use chrono::{DateTime, Local, TimeZone};
    use serde::{self, Deserialize, Deserializer};

    const FORMAT: &str = "%+";

    pub fn deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<DateTime<Local>, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        Local
            .datetime_from_str(&s, FORMAT)
            .map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)
    }
}
```

`cargo test` passes on my local mac mini (M1) but fails on `github actions` with the error

```
thread 'test::test_weather_data_ok' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("no possible date and time matching input", line: 1, column: 56)', src/controller.rs:63:65
```

Here is my YML-file on github which is the default handed out by github:

```
name: Rust

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build
      run: cargo build --verbose
    - name: Run tests
      run: cargo test --verbose
```

There is a [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151602/rust-process-failed-with-exit-code-101-using-github-actions) with a similar `exit code 101` but the error in that case was due to directory layout changes so it doesn't seem to apply in this case.

Omitting the as_bytes() in the test gives the same error.

Comment: Can you provide the datetime type being deserialized? And does it reproducibly fail when just trying to parse the date only?

Comment: Yes, will add the struct that is used in deserializing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `chrono` states that `datetime_from_str` will only succeed if there's no time zone in the text or the time zone matches the target `TimeZone`, which explains the failure if the time zone is different. The docs point to `DateTime::parse_from_str` to parse a `DateTime` with any time zone into a `DateTime<FixedOffset>` object, so something like this would work

```
DateTime::parse_from_str(&s, FORMAT)
            .map(Into::into)
            .map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)
```

`Into::into` is needed to map the type from `DateTime<FixedOffset>` to `DateTime<Local>` to match your return type.

That said, `chrono` implements serialization directly with rfc3339 as the default format. You need to enable the `serde` feature flag. Then you can get rid of your custom deserialization code and just go with

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Insertable)]
pub struct Reading {
    pub measurement_time_default: DateTime<Local>,
    pub id: i32,
    pub index: i32,
    pub field_description: String,
    pub measurement: f32,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the error is occurring when trying to unparse the json with serde at `let wd: Vec<Reading> = serde_json::from_str(&*weather_data).unwrap();` and it seems to be related to the timestamps in the json payload.  Usually GitHub actions are executed in UTC, which would likely be different from your local computer's clock, which can sometimes cause errors.

It's also possible that the timestamp formats supported on each platform are different, but that depends on the definition of the data structures being deserialized, which isn't shown in the question

Comment: First I dismissed the idea, wrote a comment and linked to a time zone specification at postgresql. But then I thought "Let me try to change it to UTC (+00:00)" and now the test pass. Seems like a bug. Thank you.

Comment: And fails on my local machine. Hmm.